# How do you effectively use URL parameters to manage a large number of dynamic Reports?

Tags: lightning-web-components, reporting, dynamic, custom-reports

*This question is borderline opinion based, but hopefully still acceptable.*

How do medium to large organizations manage Reports that should have dynamic parameters?

Consider a company that has thousands of accounts and dozens of reports related to the `Account` object. It's simply not practical to create a discrete report for each account that differs only by the Account Id.

One can filter reports using URL parameters as outlined here:

- [Filter Reports with URL Parameters in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_filter_url.htm&type=5)

I'm curious how people are effectively using that functionality when they have to manage a large number of Reports. If you add a Button or Link to each Account page, then you can't really add more than a small handful of them.

From the Report page, it's not clear how we could implement a ScreenFlow that could at least ask the user for which parameters they want to use, and then pass those to the Report.

We could create an entirely custom page, with a custom component, but then any time a new Report is created that needs to be "dynamic", the custom component also needs to be updated. (We could mitigate this a bit with a new custom object along the lines of 'DynamicReport', but it just feels like we're building a lot of customization for something relatively trivial.)

Larger organizations must run into this issue all the time, so I'm curious how they handle it. Our goal is to create a single "Report Template" for each Report we want to run, and then just call that Report with appropriate parameters such as an AccountId or UserId.